# NetworkManager remove device if created from systemd

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, systemd

I create `systemd` script for bring up CAN interface in my `Ubuntu 18.04` machine. Systemd script is as below:

```
[Unit]                                                                          
Description=Serial CAN adapter for %I device                                    

[Service]                                                                       
User=root                                                                       
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/can_ACM.sh %i                                          
Type=oneshot                                                                    

[Install]                                                                       
WantedBy=multi-user.target                                                      
~
```

The `can_ACM.sh` script is:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       

DEV="can0"                                                                      
TTY=$1                                                                          
BAUDRATE=1000000                                                                

slcand -s6 -S${BAUDRATE} "/dev/${TTY}" "${DEV}"                                 
sleep 1                                                                         
ip link set up ${DEV}
```

I use `NetworkManager` as renderer for `netplan` and I created configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` as below:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)                              
auto lo                                                                         
iface lo inet loopback                                                          

allow-hotplug can0                                                             
iface can0 can static                                                          
  pre-up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 1000000                     
  up /sbin/ip link set up $IFACE                                               
  down /sbin/ip link set down $IFACE
```

When I run `can_ACM.sh` script by hands as root, CAN network starts succesfully, but when I try to start it by `systemd`, `NetworkManager` removes `can0` device. Logs from `journalctl`:

```
gru 09 10:17:33  systemd[1]: Starting Serial CAN adapter for ttyACM0 device...
gru 09 10:17:33  slcand[5436]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyACM0
gru 09 10:17:33  slcand[5437]: attached TTY /dev/ttyACM0 to netdevice slcan0
gru 09 10:17:33  kernel: can0: renamed from slcan0
gru 09 10:17:33  slcand[5437]: netdevice slcan0 renamed to can0
gru 09 10:17:33  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883053.8788] manager: (can0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
gru 09 10:17:33  systemd-udevd[5440]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
gru 09 10:17:33  systemd-udevd[5440]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for slcan0
gru 09 10:17:33  systemd-udevd[5440]: Could not set offload features of slcan0: No such device
gru 09 10:17:33  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883053.9118] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/slcan0, iface: slcan0)
gru 09 10:17:33  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883053.9119] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/slcan0, iface: slcan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
gru 09 10:17:34  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883054.8523] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/can0, iface: can0)
gru 09 10:17:34  systemd[1]: Started Serial CAN adapter for ttyACM0 device.
```

When network is successfully up by runninc script by hands, logs are like below:

```
gru 09 10:24:56  slcand[8234]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyACM0
gru 09 10:24:56  slcand[8235]: attached TTY /dev/ttyACM0 to netdevice slcan0
gru 09 10:24:56  kernel: can0: renamed from slcan0
gru 09 10:24:56  slcand[8235]: netdevice slcan0 renamed to can0
gru 09 10:24:56  systemd-udevd[8237]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
gru 09 10:24:56  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883496.7958] manager: (can0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
gru 09 10:24:56  systemd-udevd[8237]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for slcan0
gru 09 10:24:56  systemd-udevd[8237]: Could not set offload features of slcan0: No such device
gru 09 10:24:56  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883496.8226] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/slcan0, iface: slcan0)
gru 09 10:24:56  NetworkManager[3901]: <info>  [1575883496.8226] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/slcan0, iface: slcan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
```

Why `NetworkManager` removes interface when its creation is triggered from systemd and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by `systemd` service: `oneshot` service is deactivated after script finished and `NetworkManager` automatically removes interface from dead `systemd` service. Adding `RemainAfterExit=yes` option to the service resolved problem.

Comment: I don't think that NetworkManager removed the device. The logging message "device added" merely informs that a device appeared, not that NetworkManager added it. Likewise for "device removed" message.

Comment: @thaller,  Device really was added after this message: if I run `ip -a` command fast between these messages, device really was enabled and even worked